# Print DevTool's Network Traffic output to webpage

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently trying to stream a DHCP video over HTML with a docker container, so far, everything has been working fine. I was only wondering if there is a way I could print the video segment that is currently being requested inside my webpage so that I can demo what's exactly happening.
(segment can be seen in chrome's devtools )
[image: Chrome devtools screenshot]

Maybe with a javascript function.